# Executing tensorflow in spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

I am using spyder to implement this example of the car-pole tunnel problem. I got the code from [Reinforcement Learning](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/01/introduction-to-reinforcement-learning-implementation/).

I am having problems executing the code. I have tried on both spyder and the terminal. The return error I receive is

```
Model output "Tensor("activation_1/Identity:0", shape=(?, 16), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 2.
```

How can I incorporate the installation of dqn to spyder, so that I am able to execute this code in spyder?

```
import numpy as np
import gym

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

#Set Relevant variables

ENV_NAME = 'CartPole-v0'

# Get the enviornment and extract the number of actions availible in the Cartpole problem

env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)

np.random.seed(123)

env.seed(123)

nb_actions = env.action_space.n

#hidden layer neural network model.

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())

policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy()
memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])

#Test model

dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=5, vizualize=True)ter co
```

Comment: Are you sure, you properly installed tensorflow? Did you validate the installation ?

Comment: Successfully downloaded tensorflow. New error: ValueError: Model output "Tensor("activation_1/Identity:0", shape=(?, 16), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 2.

Comment: I'm not sure but  please check [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462)  and [this too](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397) to get some relevant ideas.

Comment: It looks like where you say Dense(16) you need to say Dense(2)